# Maximum and minimum number from a file in C

Tags: c, file

I have a file that contains numbers separated by space and enter. And I want to find the maximum and minimum:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    char nums[500];
    int min,max,i,a;
    FILE * file;
    file = fopen ("test.txt", "r");
    i=0;
    while( fscanf(file, "%d,", &a) > 0 )
    {
        nums[i++] = a;
    }



    for(i=0; i<=sizeof(nums); i++){

          if (nums[i]>max) max=nums[i];
          if (nums[i]<min) min=nums[i];

        }
    printf("Maximum: %d\n", max);
    printf("Minimum: %d", min);

    fclose (file);
    getch();
}
```

I always get :

```
Maximum: 2686820 
Minimum: -128
```

Ok so i changed `char nums[500]` to`int nums[500]`. I initialized `max=0` and `min=INT_MAX`(USING `<limits.h>` ). **It still gives me an random value.**

How would i go forward if the numbers form the file change? is there a method to initialize an array with the specific lenght of the numbers inside the file?

Comment: Why not forget in storing those numbers and just keeping the min/max so far. (with the first number being both)

Comment: initialize value for min and max

Comment: to keep the code portable, eliminate the include of the conio.h file.  then use getchar() rather than getch()

Comment: always check the returned value from fopen() (!= NULL) to assure the operation was successful.  always check the returned value from fscanf() to assure the input/conversion format parameter(s) were successful

Comment: regarding this line: nums[i++] = a;'  it is trying to assign an integer (typically four bytes) to a character position in a character array.  Probably not what you want.

Comment: the declaration for the function: main()  should always indicate an int return type.  However, the code is missing the 'return 0;' statement just before the final closing brace.   If the code is compiled with all warnings enabled, then this problem, along with several others would be reported.  Warnings a where the compiler thinks the code is wrong (usually the compiler is correct) so, fix the warnings.

Comment: ok so i changed 'char nums[500]' to 'int nums[500]'. I initialized 'max=0' and 'min=INT_MAX'(USING <limits.h> ). It still gives me an random value.  How would i go forward if the numbers form the file change? is there a method to initialize an array with the specific lenght of the numbers inside the file?

Comment: @sergiu.m regarding your question about the array size.  One simple fix is to malloc some number of entries, then realloc, when that number of entries is input, to a larger number of entries.  However, for this program, the array is not actually needed.  (see my answer for details)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't initialize the `min` and `max` variables. Uninitialized non-static local variables, like your `min` and `max` variables, have an *indeterminate* value, and in reality they will be seemingly random. Using them without initialization leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You also don't initialize all of the array, which means that the values you don't initialize will *also* have indeterminate values.

And to add insult to injury, you're also going beyond the bounds of the array, which also leads to undefined behavior.

Oh, and if the value you read from the file is larger than can fit in a `char` it will be truncated.

Comment: You beat me to it. I was going to also suggest appropriate initial values: 0 for "max" and INT_MAX from <limits.h> for "min".

Comment: ...and with the number of edits in quick succession my upvote goes away. Nice "fastest guns in the west" gaming, there.

Comment: I initialized 'max=0' and 'min=9999' and i get: 'Maximum: 127
Minimum: -128'

Comment: That would be due to the final issue noted: you're storing int values in a char array for some reason.

Comment: ok so i need to have change char nums[] to int nums[]. How would i go forward if the numbers form the file change? is there a method to initialize an array with the specific lenght of the numbers inside?

Comment: not a good idea to assume that all the numbers are positive.  not a good idea to assume the number will be <= 9999

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, you store an `int` value read from the file in a `char` array and thus loose precision.

Answer (score 1):

You blindly assume that the file contains not more than 500 numbers - is that correct?
You blindly assume that the numbers in the file fit into char range - is this correct?

Then sizeof(nums) in the for loop always returns 500, so what happens if the file actually contained less than 500 numbers? you access memory that has not been initialized or that contains garbage.

Then you do not initialize min and max, which are also initialized with the value that currently is found in memory at that time.

(aww I didn't see the hint to the other answers...)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other post this is a solution to fix your problem (should add a little error checking the return values from `fscanf`

```
int min,max,i,a;
FILE * file;
file = fopen ("test.txt", "r");
fscanf(file, "%d,", &a);

min = max = a;
while( fscanf(file, "%d,", &a) > 0 )
{
    if (min > a) min = a;
    if (max < a) max = a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Moreover, you mentioned that

> a file that contains numbers **separated by space and enter**.

So, you have to write `fscanf(file, "%d", &a);` instead of `fscanf(file, "%d,", &a);`

That means you have to replace comma with space in the formatted string.

Comment: the %d format specifier skips over white space, so no trailing space needed

Answer (score 0):

```
the following code corrects the problems, 
compiles cleanly, 
demonstrates a proper error handling technique
eliminates the portability problem
eliminates unneeded variables
because a space is part of the 'white space' definition and 
the %d input conversion format specifier skips over white space,  
so no extra spacing in the scanf format string.



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <limits.h> // INT_MAX, INT_MIN

int main()
{
    int min = INT_MAX;
    int max = INT_MIN;
    int a; // current value read from file

    FILE * file = NULL;
    if( NULL == (file = fopen ("test.txt", "r") ) )
    { // then, fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for test.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    while( fscanf(file, "%d", &a) )
    {
        if( a < min ) min = a;
        if( a > max ) max = a;
    } // end while

    printf("Maximum: %d\n", max);
    printf("Minimum: %d\n", min); // '\n' causes output to terminal

    fclose (file);
    getchar();
    return( 0 );
} // end function: main
```